# All Combinations Of Pairs

Tags: combinatorics

> A dance class consists of 22 students, of which 10
>   are women and 12 are men. If 5 men and 5 women
>   are to be chosen and then paired off, how many
>   results are possible?

First there are 5 people to be chosen from each group so it is $12 \choose 5$$\cdot$$10 \choose 5$$=2970$ now it is like the [handshake problem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HandshakeProblem.html)?
but because there are 2 group it first need to be divided in two, so it is  $\frac{1485*1484}{2}=1101870$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After the people are chosen, line up the men in order of student number, or weight. Then any permutation of the chosen women determines a possible result, and distinct permutations give distinct results.

So for the number of possible results we multiply $\binom{10}{5}\binom{12}{5}$ by $5!$.

Comment: So baiscally we can look at the action of matching pairs as ordering the total number of pairs in a row?

Comment: Yes, but we must be careful. If we ordered both the men and women, which can be done in $(5!)^2$ ways, we would be multiply counting the pairings. That's why I gave a *fixed* ordering of the men, and worked with permutations of the women. But we could instead choose the men, $\binom{12}{5}$ way, line them up in order of weight. The fattest of the chosen men can be paired with a woman in $10$ ways. For each way, the second fattest can be paired with a woman in $9$ ways, and so on, for a total of $\binom{12}{5}(10)(9)(8)(7)(6)$.  Numerically the same answer, slightly different approach.

Comment: Just to be sure, as for the first way $10\choose 5 $$12\choose 5$\cdot 5!$, $10\choose 5 $$12\choose 5$ are the ways to choose 10 people (from the 2 groups) multiplying it by $5!$ is the ways of ordering a men corresponding to a woman?

Comment: Yes. I chose the first way for the answer because it begins more symmetrically, and anyway that's how you started.

Comment: The $5!$ is the number of ways of pairing the chosen women with the chosen men. So the full argument is very similar to yours,  except that you counted the number of pairings of $5$ chosen men with $5$ chosen women incorrectly.

Comment: whi is it a permutation? in this case order doesn't matter so shouldn't be a combination instead?